Why a Majorana spinor is real?
Two matrices $$\rho^0=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \; \text{and}\; \rho^1=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ represent two dimensional Dirac matrices which obey the Dirac algebra $\{ \rho^{\alpha},\rho^{\beta}\}=2\eta^{\alpha \beta}$. The author in the book "String theory and M-theory" says on page 110 that the fermionic world-sheet field $\psi^{\mu}$ satisfies $\{\psi^{\mu},\psi^{\nu}\}=0$. I have two questions:

Does relation $\{\psi^{\mu},\psi^{\nu}\}=0$ hold between two different Majorana spinors or between its components of one spinor or between components of two different spinors? Because if $\psi_A$ and $\psi_B$ are two spinors, then $\psi_A \psi_B=-\psi_B \psi_A$ does not have meaning since they are two columns.

Why in the representation of two-dimensional Dirac Algebra, a Majorana spinor is equivalent to a real spinor?



Concerning the title question (v6), it is more or less by definition.

General tip: Consider to only ask 1 question per post.

@Qmechanic I've just edited my question.
